# Integrate Fortran, C++ with R

Tags: c++, r, fortran, rcpp, armadillo

My task it to rewrite a R function in C++ to accelerate the while loops. All R codes has been rewritten in the help of Rcpp and Armadillo except the `.Fortran()`. I try to use Rinside to at first and it works at a very slow speed as Dirk indicated. (It is expensive for data to go through R -> C++ -> R -> Fortran)

Since I don't want to rewrite the Fortran codes in C++ and vice versa, it looks natural to accelerate the programs by linking C++ directly to Fortran: R -> C++ -> Fortran.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

extern "C"{
   List f_(int *n,NumericMatrix a, NumericVector c, double* eps);
}
```

The problem is that I can integrate C++ with Fortran and integrate R with C++, but I can't make these three things work together!

I try to compile the C++ in Linux but it just can't find `RcppArmadillo.h` and `namespace Rcpp`:

```
 error: RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory
 error: 'Rcpp' is not a namespace-name
```

When I call `sourceCpp("test.cpp")` in R directly, the console would display:

```
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x20b2): undefined reference to `f_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Error in sourceCpp("test.cpp") : Error occurred building shared library.
```

I also try to combine all these things in a package by

```
RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("TTTest")
```

But I don't know how to deal with the package `TTTest` (I believe it could not be installed) after I add the `.cpp` and `.f` files to `/src` and run `compileAttributes`.

So, is it possible to do things like what I imagine by Rcpp? Or it is necessary to convert Fortran codes to C/C++ codes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your compiler (well, preprocessor) is unable to find file "RcppArmadillo.h". Ensure it is in the same directory as your "*.cpp" file(s) or it's in any other way reachable (hint: "-I")

Comment: Yeah, it should be like `include "RcppArmadillo.h"` but it still cant find the other header files. And I doubt that to compile the file with Rcpp woud take more time since finally I would call the function in R

Comment: If this question is still relevant, than have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294364/8416610). The function called there is still a C function, but in the end a Fortran subroutine is used.

Answer (score 29):

I would suggest for such projects to roll your code into a package. I created a simple example of such a package I called `mixedlang` that is available at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/duckmayr/mixedlang). I will describe the process of creating the package here.

The steps I took were as follows:

1. Set up the package structure from R with `RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("mixedlang")` (I only used RcppArmadillo rather than Rcpp since the OP was -- there's nothing Armadillo specific to this example)
2. Added the C++ and Fortran code files described below to the `src/` folder
3. In R, run `Rcpp::compileAttributes("mixedlang/")` then `devtools::install("mixedlang/")`

### The Code

I created a simple C++ function whose only purpose (essentially) was to call a Fortran function. The example function takes in a numeric vector, multiplies each element by its index, and returns the result. First let's look at the Fortran code:

#### fortranfunction.f90

This function just takes in two doubles and multiplies them, returning the result:

```
REAL*8 FUNCTION MULTIPLY (X, Y) 
REAL*8 X, Y
MULTIPLY = X * Y
RETURN
END
```

#### test_function.cpp

Now we need to call this Fortran code from our C++ code. When doing this, we need to take into account a few things:

1. Fortran arguments are passed by reference, not by value.
2. Since `MULTIPLY` is defined in another file, we need to declare it in our C++ file so the compiler knows the argument and return types.

   a. When declaring the Fortran function for our C++ file, we'll drop the case of the function name and append an underscore, since the Fortran compiler should do this by default.

   b. We have to declare the function within an `extern "C"` linkage specification; C++ compilers cannot typically use function names as unique identifiers since it allows overloading, but for calling Fortran functions, we need it to do exactly that which the `extern "C"` linkage specification accomplishes (see, for example, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/8386140)).

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// First we'll declare the MULTIPLY Fortran function
// as multiply_ in an extern "C" linkage specification
// making sure to have the arguments passed as pointers.
extern "C" {
    double multiply_(double *x, double *y);
}

// Now our C++ function
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test_function(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
    // Get the size of the vector
    int n = x.size();
    // Create a new vector for our result
    Rcpp::NumericVector result(n);
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        // And for each element of the vector,
        // store as doubles the element and the index
        double starting_value = x[i], multiplier = (double)i;
        // Now we can call the Fortran function,
        // being sure to pass the address of the variables
        result[i] = multiply_(&starting_value, &multiplier);
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Example output

After installing the package, I ran as an example

```
mixedlang::test_function(0:9)
# [1]  0  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64 81
```

### Likely sources of the original poster's problems

1. When attempting to compile initially, they did not let the compiler know where `RcppArmadillo.h` was.
2. Trying to do this with `sourceCpp` is just asking for trouble; it wasn't really made to handle multiple files (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43820385/8386140) by [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel)), which is necessary when dealing with multiple languages.

I'm not sure what happened when they tried to roll it into a package, which is why I drew up this example.

Comment: Nicely done, and needs more exposure.  Would you be open to doing an Rcpp Gallery post along the same lines?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Absolutely

Comment: Interesting, in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories it says: "It is not portable (and may not be possible at all) to mix all these languages in a single package, and we do not support using both C++ and Fortran 9x." Maybe that statement has to be reconsidered! Or maybe it works because you are not interfacing R with Fortran directly?

Comment: @RalfStubner Good catch on the R Extensions manual! I am kind of surprised to see that statement there, but I think there's something to the last sentence in your comment -- it is likely because the interface to Fortran is strictly from C++. R can only call Fortran subroutines, not functions, etc., while calling Fortran from C++ is no problem generally, and I see no reason why the fact that R is calling the C++ function should change that. I may update the answer with some more details on these issues.

Comment: @duckmayr Your answer is more than I expected. Thanks for this explanation.