# Compiling multiple source files in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have the following directory structure

```
my_func
    - my_func_r.cpp
    - my_func.c
    - my_func.h
    - my_func_test.c
    - matrix/
      - matrix.h
      - matrix.c
```

The `matrix` directory contains some matrix structures in `matrix.h` and some initialisation, free, print etc. functions in `matrix.c`. The `my_func.h` file is something like

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrix/matrix.h"

... some structures and templates ...
```

The `my_func.c` file is then

```
#include "my_func.h"

... helper functions ...

int my_func(...) {
    ... my_func stuff ...     
    return 0;
}
```

The `my_func_test.c` is something like

```
#include "my_func.h"

int main() {
    ... some test ...
    return 0;
}
```

With `gcc/g++` I can run this fine with

```
gcc my_func_test.c my_func.c matrix/matrix.c -o test -lm
```

The final file `my_func_r.cpp` is an interface between the `Rcpp` structures and the structures used in `my_func.c`. It is currently something like

```
#include "my_func.h"
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int my_func_r(Rcpp::List x, ...) {
    ... convert inputs to structure recognised by my_func.h ...       
    ... run my_func.c ...
    ... put returned objects back into one of the R structure ...

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is if I now run

```
sourceCpp('my_func_r.cpp', verbose=TRUE, rebuild=TRUE)
```

It complains about missing symbols for functions located in `matrix/matrix.c`. A workaround is to simply paste all my header and source code from both the `my_func` and `matrix` files at the top of `my_func_r.cpp`.

This however feels a very unsatisfactory solution especially for code maintenance. What is the easiest way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick ones:

1. This is not really particular to Rcpp *per se*
2. You are simply struggling with a more advanced / complicated `src/` directory in an R build.
3. There is official documentation about this in Writing R Extensions, and the questions has come up here on SO before.
4. You *could* compile a `libmatrix.a` first in the subdirectory and link to that. This is doable via a simple `src/Makevars` but *still discouraged*. So read on.
5. But this is a self-inflicted wound. Just copy `matrix.h` and `matrix.c` into `src/`, adjust the include path, and you are done.
6. As always: *Create a package*. Don't use `sourceCpp()` on larger setup. It is *not* made for that,

Comment: So unfortunately I accepted this too soon as I had copied over the `my_func_r.cpp` with all the header and source code at the top, not the original. When I do as you say and move `matrix.h` and `matrix.c` into `src/` when I try to install the package it complains `undefined symbol: _Z17freeIntegerMatrixP13IntegerMatrix`. The `freeIntegerMatrix` function is contained in `matrix.c` so it doesn't seem to be linking correctly. The tests still run fine (after a slight tweak) with the new directory architecture so I don't think this is the issue.