# Is it allowed/possible to call an R function or fortran code within a pragma openmp parallel for loop in Rcpp?

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp, spline, quantile-regression

In an Rcpp project I would like to be able to either [call an R function](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/) (the [cobs](https://github.com/cran/cobs/blob/master/R/scobs.R) function from the `cobs` package to do a concave spline fit) or [call the fortran code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396802/integrate-fortran-c-with-r?rq=1) that it relies on (the `cobs` function uses `quantreg`'s [rq.fit.sfnc](https://github.com/cran/quantreg/blob/master/R/sfn.R) function to fit the constrained spline model, which in turn relies on the fortran coded [srqfnc](https://github.com/cran/quantreg/blob/master/src/srqfnc.f) function in the `quantreg` package) within a [pragma openmp parallel for loop](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/) (the rest of my code mainly requires some simple linear algebra, so that would be no problem, but sadly each inner loop iteration also requires me to do a concave spline fit). I was wondering if this would be allowed or possible though, as I presume such calls would not be thread safe? Would there be an easy fix for this, like to surround those calls by a `#pragma omp critical` ? Would anyone have any examples of this? Or would the only way in this case involve doing a full `Rcpp` port of the `cobs` & `rq.fit.sfnc` functions first using thread-safe Armadillo classes?

Comment: The linked Fortran subroutine appears to be thread safe provided the BLAS library it uses is thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing [*the manual*](https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support):

> Calling any of the R API from threaded code is ‘for experts only’ and strongly discouraged. Many functions in the R API modify internal R data structures and might corrupt these data structures if called simultaneously from multiple threads. Most R API functions can signal errors, which must only happen on the R main thread. Also, external libraries (e.g. LAPACK) may not be thread-safe.

I have always interpreted this as "one *must not* call an R API function from threaded code". Calling an R function, irregardless of what's used inside, from inside a omp parallel region would be just that. Using `#pragma omp critical` *might* work, but if it breaks you got to keep the pieces ...

It would be safer to either re-implement the code in question or look for an existing implementation in C++/C/Fortran and call that directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - so I just tried and calling R code within a #pragma openmp parallel for loop indeed only works if one adds a #pragma omp critical... I've posted an example below... Might still have its uses though... But I'll probably have to port cobs and quantreg to Rcpp for optimal performance...

Comment: If you see anything weird in my Rcpp code let me know btw!

Answer (score 3):

So I just tried, and it seems that calling R functions within a `#pragma openmp parallel for` loop only works if it is preceded by `#pragma omp critical` (otherwise it causes a stack imbalance, and crashes R). Of course this will then cause that part of the code to execute sequentially, but this might still be useful in some cases.

Example:

The `Rcpp` part, saved as file `"fitMbycol.cpp"`:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// #define RCPP_ARMADILLO_RETURN_COLVEC_AS_VECTOR
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

#include <omp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat fitMbycol(arma::mat& M, Rcpp::Function f, const int nthreads) {

  // ARGUMENTS
  // M: matrix for which we want to fit given function f over each column
  // f: fitting function to use with one single argument (vector y) that returns the fitted values as a vector
  // nthreads: number of threads to use

  // we apply fitting function over columns
  int c = M.n_cols;
  int r = M.n_rows;
  arma::mat out(r,c);
  int i;
  omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
#pragma omp parallel for shared(out)
  for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      arma::vec y = M.col(i); // ith column of M
#pragma omp critical
{
      out.col(i) = as<arma::colvec>(f(NumericVector(y.begin(),y.end())));
}
  }

  return out;

}
```

And then in R:

First the pure R version:

(we simulate some Gaussian peak shapes with Poisson noise and then do a log-concave spline fit on them using the `cobs` function)

```
x=1:100
n=length(x)
ncols=50
gauspeak=function(x, u, w, h=1) h*exp(((x-u)^2)/(-2*(w^2)))
Y_nonoise=do.call(cbind,lapply(seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=ncols), function (u) gauspeak(x, u=u, w=10, h=u*100)))
set.seed(123)
Y=apply(Y_nonoise, 2, function (col) rpois(n,col))

# log-concave spline fit on each column of matrix Y using cobs
require(cobs)
logconcobs = function(y, tau=0.5, nknots=length(y)/10) {
  x = 1:length(y)
  offs = max(y)*1E-6
  weights = y^(1/2)
  fit.y = suppressWarnings(cobs(x=x,y=log10(y+offs), 
              constraint = "concave", lambda=0, 
              knots = seq(min(x),max(x), length.out = nknots), 
              nknots=nknots, knots.add = FALSE, repeat.delete.add = FALSE,
              keep.data = FALSE, keep.x.ps = TRUE,
              w=weights, 
              tau=tau, print.warn = F, print.mesg = F, rq.tol = 0.1, maxiter = 100)$fitted)
  return(pmax(10^fit.y - offs, 0))
}
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Y.fitted <- apply(Y, 2, function(col) logconcobs(y=col, tau=0.5)),times=5L) # 363 ms, ie 363/50=7 ms per fit
matplot(Y,type="l",lty=1)
matplot(Y_nonoise,type="l",add=TRUE, lwd=3, col=adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.2),lty=1)
matplot(Y.fitted,type="l",add=TRUE, lwd=3, col=adjustcolor("red",alpha.f=0.2),lty=1)
```

[image]

And now using `Rcpp` calling our R fitting function `logconcobs` within a `#pragma openmp parallel for loop`, enclosed with a `#pragma omp critical`:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('fitMbycol.cpp')
microbenchmark(Y.fitted <- fitMbycol(Y, function (y) logconcobs(y, tau=0.5, nknots=10), nthreads=8L ), times=5L) # 361 ms
```

OpenMP of course ends up not having any effect in this case, as the `#pragma omp critical` causes everything to execute sequentially, but in more complex examples this could still be useful.

Comment: I would get rid of all the `using namespace`. Besides that I see no obvious issues.